# My image sequence is not rendering as animation when I change resolution

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, video, resolution

[image]enter image description hereI have a sequence of images already added to Blender in a clean new blend file. Output is saved as Mp4 and the encoder is also FMpeg4. When I render it as animation it works. My images are of a different resolution though(4320*1125). So, I have to change the resolution. When I change the resolution of the render and try to render it as animation, it does not render. What do I do?

Also, when i don't change resolution, it looks stretched because the images are (4320*1125).

[image]

Here is the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wrZCgKGMA3kIxwcHQo2KHnFgVH1HnG49/view?usp=sharing

[[image: This last image is what happens when I ender in 4320*11253]

Comment: I'm no expert in video codecs, but as far as I know MPEG-4 supports up to 4096*2160 @ 60 fps, and I'm not sure if there are special image ratios accepted. So I guess this is no specific question for Blender.

Comment: maybe i don't understand your question...so just to be sure: could you provide a blend file with just 3 sample images and your settings so we can check it out? i think this should work...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann when I upload the file on Sheepit render farm, it renders it as an mp4 video. The only problem is it compresses the files and renders them in lower quality. So now I have to download all the frames individually and render them as mp4 animation on Blender itself which gives me said problem.

Comment: @Chris I uploaded a link to the blend file. and images just to see what i mean.

Comment: thank you. unfortunately i cannot see the image....can you please do file -> external data -> pack resources, save and upload again?

Comment: i inserted "my own" picture in your file - no stretching when rendering

Comment: ok, you insert 1125...you have to use even numbers, change to 1126 and it will render. you will get this error here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYDhN.png

Comment: @Chris Oh my. Thank you so much. It worked. I had no idea.

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the resolution numbers to even numbers, else it won't render.

The error message gives you a hint:

[image]